# How to display currency symbol with multiple conditions

Tags: powerbi, dax, currency-formatting

I am stuck on a client request in my PowerBI dashboard and am hoping someone here can help me find a solution.

The problem is to do with currency and currency symbols.

'Market spend' appears as a KPI card and is formatted as a number, not as currency (call it the value card). Next to it is another card that displays $ or “LC” (call it the currency card). Which one appears in the currency card depends on the the currency slicer: the user can toggle between local currency/ USD (there's a conversion in the background). When they select USD the currency card displays $, if they select Local Currency it changes to “LC”. It’s based on the following calculated field: *Currency Symbol = if ('Currency'[Currency] = "Local Currency","LC","$")*

The request I am trying to solve is to display the actual currency symbol for local currency. Meaning that if the user selects BR (for example) from the market slicer and clicks on the Local Currency toggle, the value ‘R$” will appear, not “LC”. (not the Market slicer is single select)

I have pulled in a currency/ currency symbol table. The relationship between the two tables is based on the Market – i.e. BR, FR, MX etc.

What I can imagine as a possible solution is to have another filter in action that accounts for the market slicer as well as the currency slicer but I don't know enough DAX to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not store the currency symbol in the Exchange Rate table, and just use something like LOOKUPVALUE() to retrieve the related symbol and just prepend it to the currency amount?